# How to get data from database and make download that content as pdf format in Asp.net MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have data in varbinary type in database from "Artifact" table like

**ID**   **CONTENT**
1    Some data in varbinary type

Now i want to get the "Content" column data and should download as PDF format in Users Download folder with name "Report.PDF" file.

How should i this? I have tried like

```
 public ActionResult DownloadFile(int fileId)
    {
        ResLandEntities reslandEntities = new ResLandEntities();

        var content = reslandEntities.ARTIFACT.Where(m => m.ID== fileId).FirstOrDefault();
        byte[] contents = content.CONTENT;
        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contents);



        return File(Server.MapPath("~/download/Report.PDF"), "application/pdf", text );
    }
```

But, not getting, can anybody help me

Comment: its correct what is the problem then???

Comment: by above code is reading "Report.PDF" content and reading as same and downloading as same content in report.PDf,i want to read content from database table and that content should display on downloaded file.

Comment: @sanjay..try below answer...

Comment: @sanjay...worked..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
 public ActionResult DownloadFile(int fileId)
 {
    ResLandEntities reslandEntities = new ResLandEntities();

    var content = reslandEntities.ARTIFACT.Where(m => m.ID== fileId).FirstOrDefault();
    byte[] contents = (byte[])content.CONTENT;


    return File(contents, "application/pdf");
 }
```

Comment: Getting like "Fail to load"

Comment: @sanjay..then i think when you save pdf file in database then it is not saved correcty

Comment: i have saved only data, not in the type pdf formats

Comment: yes you save data in varbinary format and in my answer that varbinary will be converted to byte array and then return file will automatically convert that byte array to pdf..@sanjay

Comment: but i have simple data which was converted to varbinary and it is showing that "fail to load"

Comment: @sanjay..strange..just put breakpoint in DownloadFile action and see proper data is coming from database and see byte conversion is proper or not...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59165/discussion-between-sanjay-and-exception).